# ActiveRecord sum and group by on sub query with sum and group by

Tags: ruby, activerecord, group-by, subquery, sum

I am trying to figure out how to sum and group on a sub-query that does a first level sum and group, in Ruby ActiveRecord.

I can get the sums of the sub-query using a named scope and a subsequent select function. That gets executed in a loop that builds a table with a row for each payment, with payment totals on the top of each cashadvance group, and totals for each syndicator group for all the syndicators cashadvances:

```
@funder
  .cashadvance_syndicators(@start_date, @end_date)
  .select("sum(amount) as amount, percent_syndicated, management_fee, residual_commission")
  .where(['cashadvance_syndicators.iso_id = ?', cs.iso_id])
  .group('cashadvance_syndicators.id')
```

where a `funder` has many cashadvances, which has many payments to borrowers in which many cashadvance syndicators participate in based on a percent of the whole loan.

I need to be able to sum the amounts in the columns selected for each syndicator.

Comment: I solved this by looping through the result of the above select and manually summing the amounts in each original group. I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: To make your code sample more readable I broke it down into separate lines for each method. Some people don't like that format, but for readability here on SO it works handily.